# AutoMapper - Very sporadic StackOverflowException on IMapper.Map<T>(...) call

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

Preface--I've spent countless hours attempting to put together a minimally reproducible test case for this, but any attempt at this and the problem magically goes away.  So below is the best I can provide at this point, but I'll update my question if I get anywhere further with this.

The TL;DR; is that when mapping, I'm getting an extremely intermittent StackOverflowException that is so elusive I can hardly ever catch it in the act, and even when I do I can't really find anything unusual.  The source object being mapped could be the same or different...there's not really any recognizable pattern to it.  I'm hoping someone out here has some ideas on how to smoke it out / make it occur more frequently so that I can get to the bottom of it.

Here's an example of a query I've been having trouble with.  It's an ASP.NET Core app targeting .NET 5, latest version of AutoMapper (including building from source code).  I'm also using MediatR to help facilitate a Command / Query architecture:

```
public async Task<DTOs.License?> Handle(GetLicenseQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Try to get a license and some basic info, return null if not found.
    DomainEntities.License lic = await _context.Licenses
    //    .Include(l => l.OwnerAccount)
    //    .Include(l => l.PreviousLicense)
    //    .Include(l => l.NextLicense)
        .Include(l => l.OrderItem)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Id == query.LicenseId);
    //if (lic == null)
    //    return null;

    //// If found, load additional details
    //await _context.Orders
    //    .Include(o => o.PurchaserAccount)
    //    .Where(o => o.Id == lic.OrderItem.OrderId)
    //    .LoadAsync();

    return _mapper.Map<DTOs.License>(lic);
}
```

I can run this with the same inputs 50 times and it might run fine.  Then it starts to throw a StackOverflowException.  Maybe it continues to do so for a few re-runs of the app, but after a while starts behaving again.  Sometimes if I stand on my head it'll throw, and then if I blow onto the keyboard super hard like an NES cartridge, it starts working again!

I have tried downloading and building the source for AutoMapper to get more details on at what point the problem occurs, and it's often in MapperConfiguration.GetExecutionPlan(MapRequest mapRequest) or maybe just a couple levels into Map().  The stack trace doesn't really look all that deep to me, but maybe I'm just missing something.

After looking for previous related issues here and on the GitHub repo, I can see that circular references in DTOs are discouraged, and which a number of my entities/DTOs do have, such as:

- License.NextLicense/PreviousLicense (self-referential)
- License.OrderItem <--> OrderItem.License
- Order.OrderItem <--> OrderItem.Order

But theoretically it sounds like AutoMapper tries to detect and handle this on its own; and besides, manual calls to PreserveReferences() and/or MaxDepth() ought to guarantee no undetected infinite cycles, but no luck on these calls.  I would try removing some of these circular references in the source objects (and have commented out some of the Include(...) calls), but the exception is so rare to begin with I have no way to really prove that removing a particular circular reference actually fixed anything.  Hence I really need to find a way to *reproduce this more consistently*.

Does anyone have any ideas or clues or tips to help me figure out what is going on here?  Am I on the wrong track looking at circular references?  I'm almost wondering if something in *rebuilding* the app causes some minor sporadically difference in the built assembly to create this problem.  Just today, I've been trying for half the day to get an exception, but no luck (probably rebuilt and ran the web app 50 times at this point).  I can try to provide additional information might be helpful, but might need to wait for the stars to align to get an actual StackOverflowException to occur again...

**UPDATE 1**

First call stack I was able to catch.  I've had to trim it down due to limited space in the SO post.  This was loading all entities in the code above (nothing was commented out).  See UPDATE 2 for more progress on this with commented out code.

```
    [Lightweight Function]  
>   AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore<BizApp.Core.Store.Order, BizApp.Services.Queries.Order>(BizApp.Core.Store.Order source, BizApp.Services.Queries.Order destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 94 C#
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.Order, BizApp.Services.Queries.Order>(BizApp.Core.Store.Order source, BizApp.Services.Queries.Order destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 71 C#
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.Order, BizApp.Services.Queries.Order>(BizApp.Core.Store.Order source, BizApp.Services.Queries.Order destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 83  C#
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.Order, BizApp.Services.Queries.Order>(BizApp.Core.Store.Order source, BizApp.Services.Queries.Order destination, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 99 C#
    [Lightweight Function]  
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore<BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem>(BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem source, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 94 C#
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem>(BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem source, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 71 C#
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem>(BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem source, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 83  C#
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem>(BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem source, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem destination, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 99 C#
    [Lightweight Function]  
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore<object, BizApp.Services.Queries.License>(object source, BizApp.Services.Queries.License destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 94   C#
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<object, BizApp.Services.Queries.License>(object source, BizApp.Services.Queries.License destination) Line 44   C#
    AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BizApp.Services.Queries.License>(object source) Line 34    C#
    BizApp.Services.dll!BizApp.Services.Queries.Licenses.GetLicenseQueryHandler.Handle(BizApp.Services.Queries.Licenses.GetLicenseQuery query, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 94    C#
    [Resuming Async Method] 
    ... Mostly EF Core calls...
    [Async Call Stack]  
    [Async] BizApp.Services.dll!BizApp.Services.ValidationBehavior<BizApp.Services.Queries.Licenses.GetLicenseQuery, BizApp.Services.Queries.License>.Handle(BizApp.Services.Queries.Licenses.GetLicenseQuery request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, MediatR.RequestHandlerDelegate<BizApp.Services.Queries.License> nextHandler) Line 183  C#
    [Async] MediatR.dll!MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior<BizApp.Services.Queries.Licenses.GetLicenseQuery, BizApp.Services.Queries.License>.Handle(BizApp.Services.Queries.Licenses.GetLicenseQuery request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, MediatR.RequestHandlerDelegate<BizApp.Services.Queries.License> next) Line 30    C#
    [Async] BizApp.Services.dll!BizApp.Services.BizMediator.ExecuteRequest<BizApp.Services.Queries.License>(BizApp.Services.IBizRequest<BizApp.Services.Queries.License> request, bool createNewScope, System.Func<SimpleInjector.Scope, System.Threading.Tasks.Task> configNewScope) Line 69   C#
    [Async] BizApp.Website.dll!BizApp.Website.Pages.BizPageModelBase.ExecuteRequest<BizApp.Services.Queries.License>(BizApp.Services.IBizRequest<BizApp.Services.Queries.License> request) Line 220 C#
    [Async] BizApp.Website.dll!BizApp.Website.Pages.BM.Licenses.DetailsModel.Compose(System.Guid? id, string licenseNumber) Line 62 C#
    [Async] BizApp.Website.dll!BizApp.Website.Pages.BM.Licenses.DetailsModel.OnGet(System.Guid? id, string licenseNumber) Line 35   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult>(object taskAsObject) Line 145   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments) Line 138   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync() Line 275    C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync() Line 649   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync() Line 649   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAwaitedAsync() Line 683    C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageModel.OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.PageHandlerExecutingContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next) Line 1850   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() Line 89   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter.__Awaited|24_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker invoker, System.Threading.Tasks.Task lastTask, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted) Line 963  C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync.__Awaited|19_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker invoker, System.Threading.Tasks.Task lastTask, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted) Line 237 C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync.__Logged|17_1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker invoker) Line 172   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke.__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Endpoint endpoint, System.Threading.Tasks.Task requestTask, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger) Line 80   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 111  C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate next, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy policy, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult) Line 49 C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 92  C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 77  C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 95    C#
    [Async] MiniProfiler.AspNetCore.dll!StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfilerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 105   C#
    [Async] SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.dll!SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.RequestScopingStartupFilter.ConfigureRequestScoping.AnonymousMethod__4_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> next)  Unknown
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>.ProcessRequestAsync() Line 39   C#
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.HandleRequest() Line 674    C#
```

**UPDATE 2**
Was able to substantially trim down the EF Core query--it now just loads a License and its OrderItem.  Nothing else (no parent "Order" or otherwise).  Even so, I've now run into a couple exceptions that end with internal AutoMapper calls to Map objects that are null (not loaded).  For instance, an exception throws on the following line in Mapper.MapCore(...):

```
return ConfigurationProvider.GetExecutionPlan<TSource, TDestination>(MapRequest())(source, destination, context);
```

Partial Call Stack:

```
    >   AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore<BizApp.Core.CRM.PurchaseLog, BizApp.Services.Queries.PurchaseLog>(BizApp.Core.CRM.PurchaseLog source, BizApp.Services.Queries.PurchaseLog destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 94 C#
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BizApp.Core.CRM.PurchaseLog, BizApp.Services.Queries.PurchaseLog>(BizApp.Core.CRM.PurchaseLog source, BizApp.Services.Queries.PurchaseLog destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 71 C#
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map<BizApp.Core.CRM.PurchaseLog, BizApp.Services.Queries.PurchaseLog>(BizApp.Core.CRM.PurchaseLog source, BizApp.Services.Queries.PurchaseLog destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 83  C#
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map<BizApp.Core.CRM.PurchaseLog, BizApp.Services.Queries.PurchaseLog>(BizApp.Core.CRM.PurchaseLog source, BizApp.Services.Queries.PurchaseLog destination, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 99 C#
        [Lightweight Function]  
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore<BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem>(BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem source, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 94 C#
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem>(BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem source, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 71 C#
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem>(BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem source, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 83  C#
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map<BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem>(BizApp.Core.Store.OrderItem source, BizApp.Services.Queries.OrderItem destination, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 99 C#
        [Lightweight Function]  
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore<object, BizApp.Services.Queries.License>(object source, BizApp.Services.Queries.License destination, AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context, System.Type sourceType, System.Type destinationType, AutoMapper.IMemberMap memberMap) Line 94   C#
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<object, BizApp.Services.Queries.License>(object source, BizApp.Services.Queries.License destination) Line 44   C#
        AutoMapper.dll!AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BizApp.Services.Queries.License>(object source) Line 34    C#
        BizApp.Services.dll!BizApp.Services.Queries.Licenses.GetLicenseQueryHandler.Handle(BizApp.Services.Queries.Licenses.GetLicenseQuery query, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 102   C#
```

I never loaded the `PurchaseLog` entity from EF Core, it's null.  I've since run into a similar stack trace where AutoMapper fails on mapping a null `Order`, also not loaded.

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build. You can also try `ProjectTo` instead. And then you don't need `Include` anymore.

Comment: Also what's the purpose of calling `Map` to the same type (`License` -> `License`)?

Comment: Have you tried [performance profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio? Look for memory or CPU usage spikes. You can write a snippet using local db to just run only your piece of code thousands of times in repeat and see how this look on the profiler and if it throws. With the profiling results you can disable the circular references/includes and look for any differences. Circular reference would be my bet too, as I suppose mapping such a thing could somehow create a nasty endless mapping recursion.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I actually tried building from the AutoMapper source code from GitHub, but that didn't really tell me a whole lot.  I'm familiar with projecting via Select with basic LINQ, but was not aware this was a built-in feature of AutoMapper.  I'll need to read up on this and see if it is something I can take advantage of.  If my problem is a circular reference issue, I wonder how ProjectTo might handle these differently from Map...

Comment: @IvanStoev, good catch.  In cleaning up the code that I posted here, I removed a bit too much.  The source and destination "Licenses" are separate classes in different namespaces.  I'll update my post to clarify this.

Comment: @Prolog, good suggestion, I've not tried running with a profiler.  Catching this exception in the act with a profiler might yield additional clues, though again I have to trigger the problem somehow in the first place, and that's the problem--it's so illusive!  I'll give it a try and see where I get.  This is a side-project from my main work, so it might take a few days to work on this.

Comment: @GlennSills, if I can catch the exception in the act again I will post the stack trace.  But as mentioned in my post, when I have caught it in the past (should have saved a copy), the stack is pretty "shallow" as far as AutoMapper calls go--at least what VS's Call Stack pane shows--typically most of the frames involve ASP.NET Core calls and just a few frames with AutoMapper, usually ending in either MapperConfiguration.GetExecutionPlan(...) or some sub-call into Map (can't remember the exact method name, or reproduce at the moment) that doesn't go very deep.

Comment: It seems to me like the async part takes a lot of stack. So definitely try to make a repro without anything async. If you can't, then the whole AM thing might be a red herring.

Comment: I noticed the frames between [Resuming Async Method] and [Async Call Stack] all "go away" at some point while clicking around in the call stack--leaving a much shorter overall stack which I think better represents the state of things during the exception.  I have wondered if AM isn't the root problem here, but proving so is easier said than done.  In 20 years of developing this is probably the most maddening bug I've ever run into--it's just so random and rare in occurrence.  I'll keep trying and post updates as I find them, but I need a sanity break...maybe stepping away for a bit will help.

Comment: Update to post--was able to comment nearly all "Include(...)" calls and subsequent call to load "Order" and still throw the exception.  Also was able to get a couple more StackOverflowExceptions, provided in UPDATE 2.  Next step--will attempt to reproduce outside of an async environment when I can.  Previous attempts to reproduce outside my app environment haven't succeeded, but fingers crossed this time I can...

Answer (score -1):

For anyone interested I may have figured out the problem.  As mentioned above, my DTOs have circular references, such as Order <--> OrderItem, OrderItem <--> Order, License <--> OrderItem, etc.  There are many other DTOs beyond just these, which create a sort of interlinked graph--Contact, Account, HistoryItem (and derived classes of HistoryItem such as a PurchaseLog), etc.

For any given Query, only a small subset of entities is ever loaded.  For instance, in trying to debug this issue, I got the EF Core query down to just a License and OrderItem.  But still a StackOverflowException.  So I tried modifying my License and OrderItem DTOs to remove any circular reference between them, but still no luck.

What seems to have made the difference is to also remove *all circular reference properties in the other DTO objects,* irrespective of whether they're used in the current query.  This didn't seem obvious or necessary since no db entities relating to these other objects were ever loaded.  But so far it's been smooth sailing since I did this.  Looking back at the stack trace during the StackOverflowException, it was often either in `MapperConfiguration.GetExecutionPlan(...)` or in `MapCore(...)` for some entity / DTO that was never loaded in the first place (such as an Order or PurchaseLog, where as mentioned above I only ever loaded License and OrderItem entities).

So my current theory is that AutoMapper has an issue somewhere in what I'll call the "pre-mapping" process--when calling `IMapper.Map(...)` it is apparently running through a sort of metadata on my larger graph of interconnected DTOs (beyond what entities were actually loaded), and getting into some recursive loop.

I don't know if this is a case of "don't do that" as far as having so many circular references, or a genuine bug in AutoMapper.  But at this point with a solution in sight, I'm just going to rebuild my DTO's to minimize circular references, which is no small task but probably still a faster approach than continuing to struggle to further isolate this issue.